# Parameter passed to WebApi method is null on reaching method body

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am setting up a simple MVC project as I want to expand my knowledge outside of the scope of Umbraco where I usually do this sort of project.

I am familiar with WebApi but cannot seem to get it to work in this instance.

I have a datepicker in my view that is initialised with the following Javascript:

```
$('#id-tour_0').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "Content/themes/base/images/icon_calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/tour/requesttours',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(date),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

This then posts to the following WebApi method upon making a selection in the datepicker:

```
public class TourController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public string RequestTours([FromBody] String request)
        {
            return request;
        }
    }
```

With my WebApiConfig.cs setup as follows:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

However, when I breakpoint my WebApi method I can see that request is coming up as null. Why is this and how can I get it to receive the value that is posted by my Javascript?

N.B. I have checkeed in Firebug and the correct date is being posted correctly to the method

[image]

Comment: how you set your data value it is almost empty, where you send it you must be specify with parameter  name, if have   data: '{request:"'+ date.Date +'"}'

Answer (score 2):

Post parameter name should map to the name of the function argument in your class file

So create a object like this

```
var dateX = new Object();
dateX.request = date.Date;
```

Then send this object in your ajax call

```
data: JSON.stringify(dateX),
```

or directly pass the object like this

```
data: '{request:"'+ date.Date +'"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
$('#id-tour_0').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "Content/themes/base/images/icon_calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/tour/requesttours',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {Date: date},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Then I created a new object in my C# code that I mapped the request parameter to:

```
public class TourController : ApiController
    {
        public string RequestTours([FromBody] DateRequest request)
        {
            return request.Date;
        }
    }

    public class DateRequest
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```